# How to initialize global pointer to extern variable?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, extern

Lets say I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t *ptr;
} Example;
```

If I have in file1.c:

```
// Global variable
uint8_t myVar;
```

How can I initialize an `Example` with the `ptr` member pointing to `myVar`, in file2.c?

I know I could just do:

```
extern uint8_t myVar;
// Global variable
Example myExample = {.ptr = &myVar};
```

But myVar would be visible in all the scope of file2.c and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Does `myExample` also have to be a global variable? And what is the *original* and *underlying* problem you need to solve? Why do you think this solution is the best (or only) way? Why do you want to avoid `extern uint8_t myVar;`?

Comment: Then create a "getter" function in`file1` which will return the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer or other object can be made available within a source file without making symbols used in its initializers be visible by declaring it `extern` in one source file (or more) and defining it in a separate source file.

Create a separate C file, such as `myExample.c`, containing a definition of `myExample`:

```
#include "myExample.h"

extern uint8_t myVar;
Example myExample = { .ptr = &myVar };
```

Create a header file, such as `myExample.h`, that declares `myExample`:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t *ptr;
} Example;

extern Example myExample;
```

Then include the header file in any source file where you want to use `myExample`. That source file will see `myExample` but not `myVar`.

Also compile the new C file and link it in with your program.

Comment: That's quite clever, I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the function in the file.c

```
static uint8_t myVar;

uint_8 *getMyVat(void)
{
    return &myvar;
}
```

in file2.c

```
void foo(void)
{
     Example myExample = {.ptr = getMyVar()};
}
```

But it cannot be used as an initialisation of the static storage variables

Comment: can --> cannot?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes indeed

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland  We cannot access static variables in another file, right??

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula  and .....? What is the point of this comment?

Comment: You are trying to access static variable in another file. Static variable scope is limited to the file only.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula No, you do not understand how it works. You can access if you know its reference. `stati`c global variables just do not have external linkage, but it is something completelly different.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot. C language has only 3 scopes:

- global scope is (potentially) visible to the whole program (across different compilation units)
- static scope is visible to a compilation unit
- local scope is visible to the block where the variable is declared

If you want to initialize a global or static variable, its initializers can only contain global or static symbols, which have to be visible throughout all the source file.

Comment: None of C’s four scopes are named “global,” “static,” or “local”. There is *file* scope (for the current translation unit), *block* scope (starting in a block or the parameter declarations of a function definition and ending with the end of the block), *function prototype* scope (within the parameter declarations of a non-definition function declaration), and *function* scope (for labels). Linkage can connect symbols across translation units but is not a scope.